# Retrieve DynamoDB table entry from DynamoDB stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

In my application, a lambda is triggered from a DynamoDB stream. When invoked, lambda saves the DynamoDB stream data in a DB. Below information is included in the stream,

```
 {
 "id": "3826d26b-7dff-419e-afba-c8dd8fbfeded",
 "createdAt": "2023-07-25T03:38:49.974Z",
 "data": {
  "DDBStreamBatchInfo": {
   "approximateArrivalOfFirstRecord": "2023-07-20T10:44:30Z",
   "approximateArrivalOfLastRecord": "2023-07-20T10:44:30Z",
   "batchSize": 1,
   "endSequenceNumber": "7755608300000000009920716151",
   "shardId": "shardId-00000001689839413006-7931cd0d",
   "startSequenceNumber": "7755608300000000009920716151",
   "streamArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxx:table/prod-iot-vision-data-ingestion/stream/2022-10-07T03:38:45.908"
  },
  "requestContext": {
   "approximateInvokeCount": 1,
   "condition": "RetryAttemptsExhausted",
   "functionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxx:function:prod-iot-vision-data-transformation-subscriber",
   "requestId": "64f894c1-5003-47a9-a7fa-3196a1dcdd1a"
  },
  "responseContext": {
   "executedVersion": "$LATEST",
   "functionError": null,
   "statusCode": 200
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-07-20T10:44:31.848Z",
  "version": "1.0"
 }
}
```

Now I need to get the entry in the original DynamoDB table again from this stream batch info. (From another lambda)

How can I do that?

Comment: The batch info just contains some metainformation about the record(s) it sent to your Lambda. The actual data is in those records. From the information you showed us you won't be able to entries.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements aren't clear, which makes it difficult to answer correctly. But with a DynamoDB stream, all of the modifications made to an item are projected into the stream, including the items keys. You can then use those keys from your second Lambda function to read the item.

But a more cost-effective and performant approach would be to pass the payload from the stream consumer Lambda to the second stream requiring the item. But it's hard to know your exact requirements.